# What does Allah mean by "I am time"?

Tags: hadith, allah, hadith-interpretation, time

[4th Hadith in Hadith Qudsi](http://sunnah.com/qudsi40/4) is as follows

> Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
>
> > Allah said: Sons of Adam inveigh against [the vicissitudes of] Time, and **I am Time**, in My hand is the night and the day

Time, as it stands at present, is considered a dimension (the 4th dimension) .

The hadith continues to say

> to inveigh against misfortunes that are part of Time is tantamount to inveighing against Him

Does anyone have a clear idea about what Allah means by *I am time*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although, this hadith's style looks like a verse, but I saw a different hadith saying the same thing but in the mouth of Mohammad(puh) (like ...Allah is the time...).

Back to your question, this hadith has been said because some people were condemning time as the responsible for aging. When the Prophet(puh) heard this, said this hadith. It means "Don't condemn the time for aging, because actually Allah is responsible for aging and you are condemning Him unwittingly. What you think time's work is actually Allah's work.".

Its like condemning a blade for a murder. Actually you should condemn the killer. In this case "The killer is the blade" means that "It isn't the blade which kills, but the killer.". Thus if you condemn time for aging, you would condemn the actual responsible (Allah) unwittingly. But of course, you shouldn't condemn Allah.

I hope this answer will be satisfying.